# Container size constraints work only in scaffold

Tags: flutter, dart

I think the answer might be simple but I didn't find it around here.
Why are the size constraints of a container ignored when it is not a child of a scaffold. So this displays the expected result:

```
    return Scaffold(
      body: Container(
        height: 10,
        width: 10,
        color: Colors.green,
      ),
    );
```

but this displays a full screen container:

```
    return Container(
        height: 10,
        width: 10,
        color: Colors.green,
    );
```

Please enlighten me!

Comment: Here it will show  you why the container displays full screen https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Container-class.html.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is caused by a difference in constraints.

Consider a screen of 800x600.

The very first widget passed to `runApp` will receive this constraint:

```dart
BoxConstraint(
  minWidth: 800,
  maxWidth: 800,
  minHeight: 600,
  maxHeight: 600,
)
```

This forces that widget to fill the screen.

From there, by adding a `Scaffold`, it will "loosen" the constraints, which then becomes:

```dart
BoxConstraint(
  minWidth: 0,
  maxWidth: 800,
  minHeight: 0,
  maxHeight: 600,
)
```

This allows the widget to be smaller than full screen.

If you want a behavior similar to `Scaffold` but without it, you can do:

```dart
runApp(
  Center(
    child: Container(color: Colors.red, width: 42, height: 42),
  ),
);
```

Comment: Thanks! That makes sense.